# How to use splitapply/findgroups on clustered/non-sequential graphs?

Tags: matlab, nodes, graph-theory, vertices, split-apply-combine

I need to implement splitapply function to non-sequential node index in graph.

I implemented the splitapply function on a graph that has non-sequential clusters. The index numbers of the returned clusters were sequentially numbered but the graph vertices are not sequentially numbered.
I want it to return the exact node indices from the original graph.

```
S={' 1',' 1',' 2',' 6',' 6',' 8'};
T={' 2',' 3',' 3',' 8',' 9',' 9'};
weight=[2; 2; 2; 2; 2; 2];
G=graph(S,T,weight);

plot(G)
bins=conncomp(G);
clusters = splitapply(@(x) {x}, 1:numnodes(G), bins);
```

**The actual results:** `clusters: [1,2,3];[4,5,6]`
**The expected results:** `clusters: [1,2,3];[6,8,9]`

[sample graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGUmo.png)

Comment: I get `clusters = {[1 2 3], 4, 5, [6 8 9], 7}` (tested in R2017b and in R2018b). Can you check?

Comment: @LuisMendo thanks for your prompt response. Nodes 4, 5 and 7 are not meant to be part of the results. I have added the .mat file of the cluster node I used which is not giving me the expected result.

Comment: @LuisMendo mine is still returning clusters: [1,2,3];[4,5,6]. How do I force it to return the exact node numbers on the graph shown? Thanks.

Comment: I got an error trying to load the file. Anyway, you should post a mininal code example that reproduces the problem, rather than link a .mat file

Comment: @LuisMendo I have added the minimal code that reproduces the problem. You can try it yourself.

Comment: After your fode, try something like `nodes = table2array(G.Nodes); result = cellfun(@(x) nodes(x), clusters, 'uniformoutput', false)`

Comment: @LuisMendo. Thank you once again. The code executed and I was able to access the contents of the clusters with "result{:}" which returned the exact node numbers.

Comment: Great! I posted it as an answer so that you can accept if you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your code, try something like

```
nodes = table2array(G.Nodes);
result = cellfun(@(x) nodes(x), clusters, 'uniformoutput', false);
```